# SWIG - Garbage Collection using %newobject

Tags: c, swig

In my C code, I have the following structure :

```
typedef struct my_structure{
    char* str1;
    char* str2;
}MyStruct;
```

And a function that returns a MyStruct pointer :

```
MyStruct* foo();
```

Inside foo, I have allocated memory for MyStruct , str1 and str2, as follows:

```
MyStruct* obj = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));

obj.str1 = malloc(256);
obj.str2 = malloc(256);
```

I want to call foo from python, java, C# and PHP and I don't want to have any memory leak in this process.

I am not sure if writing:

```
%newobject foo;
MyStruct* foo();
```

guarantees that the garbage collector will free memory for both the structure and the strings inside it.

I didn't want to obligate the caller to explicit free memory for str1 and str2 as I was looking for an automatic way of freeing memory. Is this possible?

Do I have to use "newfree" typemap in this case?

I would greatly appreciate if you could provide me an example showing the best way to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`typemap(newfree)` frees the memory used by the returned `%newobject` immediately, such as when a char* return value is converted into a Python string and the allocated object is no longer needed.  I think what you want is `%extend` the class wrapper that SWIG generates around your C structure to provide a destructor:

```
%newobject foo;

%extend MyStruct {
    ~MyStruct() {
       free($self->str1);
       free($self->str2);
    }
}
```

Please comment if this solves your issue.  This is based on my own experimentation with what I could find in the SWIG documentation and worked correctly in the simple wrapper I generated.

Comment: I have just finished the memory monitoring tests on Python and this solution worked perfectly. The GC was able to call the destructor and no memory was left allocated. I must now test it on Java, C# and PHP, but I am pretty sure it will work just fine as well. Thanks Mark.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried to get this working using newobject and newfree and everything kept crashing.