# SWIG-Python: How to garbage collect int pointer

Tags: python-2.7, swig

I have a big C project and I want to expose it's API to python by using SWIG.
For that, I have a script for generating automatically the interface file for swig (.i file).
For each type defined in the project, the script adds to the interface file %pointer_functions and %array_functions for that type.
Those directives create set of functions including a "new" function which in turn allocates memory.
Is there a way to automatically deallocate that memory when the object is garbage collected instead of calling explicitly the "delete" function?

I have a solution for structs, using the %newobject directive and %extend with destructor definition which free the allocated memory - similar to the solution in this post [SWIG - Garbage Collection using %newobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576597/swig-garbage-collection-using-newobject) .
But it doesn't work on primitive types like int, enum, etc...
Any ideas how to solve it for such types?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] showing how your currently solution leaks.

Comment: It sounds like you might making this more complicated than you have to with SWIG, although it's hard to say for certain with what you've shown. Perhaps have a look at `%array_class` instead.

Comment: Agree with @Flexo - more complicated than needed. I would not recommend to start automatically generating interface files before you have found a better alternative. Look into `%array_class` and `%array_functions`. If you have many input and output arrays of primitives, look into `numpy.i`